# Force IIS Express to Classic Pipeline Mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

How can I force IIS Express to run at classic mode? And I need that this configuration stays with .csproj, once that this file that say that a project should be open with IIS Express.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 select the Web Application project node in Solution Explorer then either:

- Press <kbd>F4</kbd>

or

- Navigate to `View -> Properties Window or press F4`

**Important:** Don't `Right-click -> Properties` from the right-click context menu for the project node in solution explorer because that will show the *Property Pages* for the project which is a whole different thing.

In the properties Windows you'll see the entry for *Managed Pipeline Mode*:

[image]

In Visual Web Developer 2010 Express it's more or less the same, again select the web project except press <kbd>F4</kbd> to get that property page:

[image]

The only caveat is that if you share the project with others (say via source control), this setting isn't stored in the `.csproj` file but in the IIS Express `applicationHost.config` file specific to your user profile. So you'd need to ensure others configured this property in their own local `applicationHost.config` files in:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config
```

All of the above also works with Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.

Answer (score 10):

option-1:
In Visual Studio goto WebSite/WebApplication properties and change `Managed Pipeline Mode` to 'Classic'.

option-2:
Open `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config` and locate your site in "Sites" section and change the app pool to classic (say `Clr4ClassicAppPool`).

If you want all the WebApplications/WebSites that you are going to create in Visual Studio to run in 'Classic' mode (by default), then in `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config` file, then change the `applicationDefaults` app pool as shown below.

```
<sites>
 ........
 ........
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4ClassicAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

Comment: I didn´t found anything named ManagedPipelineMode at WebApplication properties