# Run Two Projects on Same Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-express, edit-and-continue

I have two web projects that I want to run in the same domain in VS2010. How do I do this, still keep edit and continue, and still load Http Modules?

I tried the following:

- specifying the same port in project settings with different virtual paths on Visual Studio Development Server, but the second project won't start.
- Local IIS 7.5 Server, but it won't let me edit and continue, and my HTTP Module projects aren't loaded.
- Local IIS Express, but my HTTP Module projects aren't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

For **Edit and Continue** working with **Local IIS**, you can set global environment variable using administrator command line:

```
setx /m COMPLUS_ForceEnC 1
```

and then restart IIS.

One disadvantage is that in this case every managed process will reserve extra memory for Edit and Continue. See more about this environment variable [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/04/29/net-enc-support-for-lambdas-and-other-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/).

In Windows 10, the variable can be defined per application pool, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509545/1903736).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way:

Use IIS Express and change the managed pipeline mode to classic (instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5918197/2503659) so that HTTP modules will be loaded.