# Edit and Continue using a Local IIS

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, edit-and-continue

Is it possible to have the **Edit and Continue** option enabled on Visual Studio when debugging using **Local IIS** instead of IIS express?

Comment: Did you find an solution?

Answer (score 34):

Works in IIS 10.0 (Win 10):

In Administrator command line run

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set apppool "DefaultAppPool" /+environmentVariables.add[@start,name='COMPLUS_ForceEnC',value='1']
```

(replace `DefaultAppPool` with app pool name you're using)

This will add tag

```xml
    <environmentVariables> 
        <add name="COMPLUS_ForceEnC" value="1" /> 
    </environmentVariables>
```

into `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` for your app pool, so the app pool process always runs in Edit and Continue mode.

More on the `COMPLUS_ForceEnC` environment variable can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/04/29/net-enc-support-for-lambdas-and-other-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/).

See also [IIS Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults/environmentvariables/add)

Comment: You can also set this environment variable for the whole machine in "Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables..." or by using the powershell command: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("COMPLUS_ForceENC", "1", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

Comment: @kevinpo I don't think this is a good idea. It will cause **all**  .NET apps reserve more memory to run in "Edit and Continue" mode. This is not something that you want globally in the system.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Ondrej answer, here is a simple code to enable edit-and-continue on all your application-pools in one click:

```
SET "APPCMD=%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%f IN ('%APPCMD% list apppool /text:name') DO %APPCMD% set apppool "%%~f" /+environmentVariables.add[@start,name='COMPLUS_ForceEnC',value='1']
PAUSE
```

save this code as "Enable Edit And Continue.bat" and run it (right click on the file and choose "Run as Administrator").

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

IIS 10 on Windows 11:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='DefaultAppPool'].environmentVariables.[name='COMPLUS_ForceEnC',value='1']" /commit:apphost
```

Applied configuration changes to section "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"